# Trigger hook's method when a method called internally

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, methods, hook

I'm using CodeIgniter hook, which I've defined like below:

```
$hook['post_controller'][] = 
    array(
        'class'    => 'notify',
        'function' => 'sendEmail',
        'filename' => 'notify.php',
        'filepath' => 'controllers'
    );
```

And it's getting called whenever user browse a url. After each method got executed it's trigger the above hook. This is working fine the way I want.

Let's say I'm browsing something like: `https://localhost/dashboard/index` which will run `dashboard` controller `index` method and then trigger my hook.

Now the problem is I'm calling another method `list` of dashboard class from `index` method. So when index method called `list` method and it's got executed I want to trigger the hook as well, which is not happening right now.

Anyone help me on this!

Comment: if you are calling $this->list()  from index method its won't trigger hook as its normal class base function calling, You can do one thing instead of calling 
$this->list() , you can called redirect("dashboard/list");
Another solution is you can call it manually like this -->
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236612/calling-invoking-a-hook-manually-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

you can use flag to decide your hook run or not. for example:
in your list method on dashboard controller:

```
$this->process_email = FALSE;
```

then in your hook notify. you need to check the flag before do any process.

```
function sendEmail(){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if (property_exists($CI, "process_email") && $CI->process_email === FALSE)
    {
        return;
    }

   //`do your stuff here to send email..


}`
```